# Spotify Remote SDK For Android - AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: android, authentication, spotify, android-fingerprint-api

The steps that have been taken thus far to integrate the Spotify Remote SDK into an android application are:

1) Created application profile on Spotify Dashboard,

2) Generated Debug Fingerprint

3) Generated Release Fingerprint

4) Ensured package name is correct from running ' this.getPackageName() ' which the value is placed into Spotify Dashboard alongside the fingerprint.

I am able to run my application and upon initial launch, the spotify authentication page does present itself. However after 1 or 2 days, and into debugging, Out of nowhere the function connect(_:) fails and returns AuthenticationFailedException error

```
if (SpotifyAppRemote.isSpotifyInstalled(this)) {

        ConnectionParams connectionParams =
                new ConnectionParams.Builder(CLIENT_ID)
                        .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
                        .showAuthView(true)
                        .build();

        SpotifyAppRemote.connect(this, connectionParams,
                new Connector.ConnectionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(SpotifyAppRemote spotifyAppRemote) {
                        musicPlayer = spotifyAppRemote;
                        Log.d(TAG, "Connected! Yay!");
                    }

                    public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
                        if (error instanceof SpotifyRemoteServiceException) {
                            if (error.getCause() instanceof SecurityException) {
                                logError(error, "SecurityException");
                            } else if (error.getCause() instanceof IllegalStateException) {
                                logError(error, "IllegalStateException");
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof NotLoggedInException) {
                            logError(error, "NotLoggedInException");
                        } else if (error instanceof AuthenticationFailedException) {
                            logError(error, "AuthenticationFailedException");
                        } else if (error instanceof CouldNotFindSpotifyApp) {
                            logError(error, "CouldNotFindSpotifyApp");
                        } else if (error instanceof LoggedOutException) {
                            logError(error, "LoggedOutException");
                        } else if (error instanceof OfflineModeException) {
                            logError(error, "OfflineModeException");
                        } else if (error instanceof UserNotAuthorizedException) {
                            logError(error, "UserNotAuthorizedException");
                        } else if (error instanceof UnsupportedFeatureVersionException) {
                            logError(error, "UnsupportedFeatureVersionException");
                        } else if (error instanceof SpotifyDisconnectedException) {
                            logError(error, "SpotifyDisconnectedException");
                        } else if (error instanceof SpotifyConnectionTerminatedException) {
                            logError(error, "SpotifyConnectionTerminatedException");
                        } else {
                            logError(error, String.format("Connection failed: %s", error));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

> logError(error, "AuthenticationFailedException"); this gets executed.

At this point, I am unsure of what is going on in the background. Does the fingerprint have to somehow be dynamically updated? Does authentication timeout and Spotify itself requires to be relogged into?

Comment: I am also facing this problem now and not many solutions are online.